# How to enable/disable ARC in an xcode project?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

If a project has already been created with ARC disabled, how do I enable it and vice versa?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Open your project and select Edit -> Refactor -> Convert to Objective-C ARC.
This will start checking your code if it is ready for the conversion.

See also Clang documentation: [Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html)

How to disable ARC has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837024/how-to-disable-xcode4-2-automatic-reference-counting)

Answer (score 50):

Following are the steps which I did and it worked for me

1. Select `Project`
2. Select `Targets`
3. From the right panel, select `Build Settings`
4. Search for "Automatic Reference Counting";
5. Locate `Apple LLVM compiler 3.0 - Language` and `Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting` and select `NO` in all three sections.

[image]

Comment: Setting to NO, will it enable or disable ARC ?
Please mention clearly in your answer

Answer (score 38):

When you migrate a project to use ARC, the -fobjc-arc compiler flag is set as the default for all Objective-C source files. You can disable ARC for a specific class using the -fno-objc-arc compiler flag for that class. In Xcode, in the target Build Phases tab, open the Compile Sources group to reveal the source file list. Double-click the file for which you want to set the flag, enter -fno-objc-arc in the pop-up panel, then click Done.

Answer (score 3):

In Xcode 5.0.2, select your project in Navigatior, select Build Settings, search for Apple LLVM 5.0 - Language - Objective C and change Objective-C Automatic Refence Counting to NO

Comment: Setting to NO, will it enable or disable ARC ?
Please mention clearly in your answer