# Unity iOS development build always yields non ARC Xcode Project

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

Unity iOS Xcode build always gives a non-ARC Xcode project. I want to have unity iOS build with ARC. How can I do that?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13899120/104790).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable/disable ARC in an xcode project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018366/how-to-enable-disable-arc-in-an-xcode-project)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to activate ARC in your project but tell XCode to deactivate it only for the Unity-generated files using the "-fno-objc-arc" option. This way you can code your own stuff with arc but dont risk any sideeffects from automatically migrating the generated code. And you can easily integrate a new export from unity without having to re-migrate it.

The -fno-objc-arc has to be set in your project settings > Build Phases > Compile Sources

regards