# Why is @autoreleasepool still needed with ARC?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, xcode4.2, automatic-ref-counting

For the most part with ARC (Automatic Reference Counting), we don't need to think about memory management at all with Objective-C objects. It is not permitted to create `NSAutoreleasePool`s anymore, however there is a new syntax:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    …
}
```

My question is, why would I ever need this when I'm not supposed to be manually releasing/autoreleasing ?

---

**EDIT:** To sum up what I got out of all the anwers and comments succinctly:

**New Syntax:**

`@autoreleasepool { … }` is new syntax for

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
…
[pool drain];
```

**More importantly:**

- ARC uses `autorelease` as well as `release`.
- It needs an auto release pool in place to do so.
- ARC doesn't create the auto release pool for you. *However:*

  - The main thread of every Cocoa app already has an autorelease pool in it.
- There are two occasions when you might want to make use of `@autoreleasepool`:

  1. When you are in a secondary thread and there is no auto release pool, you must make your own to prevent leaks, such as `myRunLoop(…) { @autoreleasepool { … } return success; }`.
  2. When you wish to create a more local pool, as @mattjgalloway has shown in his answer.

Comment: There is also a third occasion:  When you develop something that is not related to UIKit or NSFoundation. Something that uses command line tools or so

Answer (score 231, accepted):

ARC doesn't get rid of retains, releases and autoreleases, it just adds in the required ones for you. So there are still calls to retain, there are still calls to release, there are still calls to autorelease and there are still auto release pools.

One of the other changes they made with the new Clang 3.0 compiler and ARC is that they replaced `NSAutoReleasePool` with the `@autoreleasepool` compiler directive. `NSAutoReleasePool` was always a bit of a special "object" anyway and they made it so that the syntax of using one is not confused with an object so that it's generally a bit more simple.

So basically, you need `@autoreleasepool` because there are still auto release pools to worry about. You just don't need to worry about adding in `autorelease` calls.

An example of using an auto release pool:

```
- (void)useALoadOfNumbers {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10000; ++j) {
        @autoreleasepool {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
                NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(i+j)];
                NSLog(@"number = %p", number);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A hugely contrived example, sure, but if you didn't have the `@autoreleasepool` inside the outer `for`-loop then you'd be releasing 100000000 objects later on rather than 10000 each time round the outer `for`-loop.

**Update:**
Also see this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/7950636/1068248 - for why `@autoreleasepool` is nothing to do with ARC.

**Update:**
I took a look into the internals of what's going on here and [wrote it up on my blog](http://www.galloway.me.uk/2012/02/a-look-under-arcs-hood-episode-3/). If you take a look there then you will see exactly what ARC is doing and how the new style `@autoreleasepool` and how it introduces a scope is used by the compiler to infer information about what retains, releases & autoreleases are required.

Comment: `ARC doesn't get rid of retains…` But your code doesn't compile under ARC if you have a single call to any of these, so what is it that you mean?

Comment: It doesn't get rid of retains. It adds them in for you. Reference counting is still going in, it's just automatic. Hence Automatic Reference Counting :-D.

Comment: So why doesn't it add in the `@autoreleasepool` for me too? If I'm not controlling what gets autoreleased or released (ARC does that for me), how should I know when to set up an autorelease pool?

Comment: But you have control over where your auto release pools go still. There's one wrapped around your whole app by default, but you might want more.

Comment: Good question. You just have to "know". Think of adding one as akin to why one might, in a GC language, add a hint to a garbage collector to go ahead and run a collect cycle now. Maybe you know there's a ton of objects ready to be cleared out, you have a loop that allocates a bunch of temp objects, so you "know" (or Instruments might tell you :) that adding a release pool around the loop would be a good idea.

Comment: @GrahamPerks: Okay that definately clears a lot up. One final question: will there ever be a case where *not* setting up an `@autoreleasepool` block will result in crash? I would think not since you are likening it to a hint, but consider the situtation I explained in the comment below on DougW's answer.

Comment: @Mk12 - you'll always still have your outer auto release pool which will get drained. And anyway, it would never result in a crash not having one. The only thing that would happen if you didn't have one is leak objects. That's only going to cause a crash if you run out of memory.

Comment: The looping example works perfectly fine without autorelease: each object is deallocated when the variable goes out of scope.  Running the code without autorelease takes a constant amount of memory and shows pointers being reused, and putting a breakpoint on an object's dealloc shows it being called once each time through the loop, when objc_storeStrong is called.  Maybe OSX does something dumb here, but autoreleasepool is completely unnecessary on iOS.

Comment: @GlennMaynard Yes, but only because of an optimisation that ARC makes where if the caller and callee are both using ARC, then the autorelease in the return from `numberWithInt:` and subsequent retain in the caller are cancelled out. Then when the caller releases the `NSNumber`, it is the final one to hold onto it and is deallocated. But saying autorelease pools are completely unnecessary on iOS is entirely incorrect. They are still very much alive and absolutely necessary.

Comment: @GlennMaynard To put it another way - this example is contrived and sadly doesn't quite show the use of autorelease pools any more, given the new optimisation that I refer to. But imagine a world without this optimisation and the example makes full sense.

Comment: Does this mean that if I use ARC and release an object from somewhere outside the ``@autoreleasepool{}`` the object still exists until the end of the @autoreleasepool block?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, I thought ARC will insert release instead of autorelease in this case (I thought autorelease only inserted when object is used for return), so in your example, having an autorelease pool or not does not seems to matter.

Comment: Now I get it, [NSNumber numberWithInt] returns an autoreleased object. I think it's good to point it out for beginners like me.

Comment: Sorry for more comments, can not edit the previous ones --- Hmm, but doesn't assigning return result to variable number automatically cause ARC to retain it, so ARC will release it after the current loop completes. So I still do not get why autorelease pool is necessary.

Comment: I think the example could be updated, but correct me if im wrong the autorelease pool will be useful if making lots of objects marked with `__autoreleasing` [(see this)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8862061/1219956), or does that compiler optimisation mentioned by @GlennMaynard still apply in this case as well?

Comment: Yes, this example needs to be updated, possibly even more contrived to show how it really makes a difference for iOS in particular

Answer (score 18):

[`@autoreleasepool`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#autoreleasepool) doesn't autorelease anything. It creates an autorelease pool, so that when the end of block is reached, any objects that were autoreleased by ARC while the block was active will be sent release messages. Apple's [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html) explains it thus:

> At the end of the autorelease pool block, objects that received an autorelease message within the block are sent a release message—an object receives a release message for each time it was sent an autorelease message within the block.

Comment: Not necessarily. The object will receive a `release` message but if the retain count is > 1 the object will NOT be deallocated.

Comment: @andybons: updated; thanks. Is this a change from pre-ARC behavior?

Comment: This is incorrect.  Objects released by ARC will be sent release messages as soon as they're released by ARC, with or without an autorelease pool.

Answer (score 10):

People often misunderstand ARC for some kind of garbage collection or the like. The truth is that, after some time people at Apple (thanks to llvm and clang projects) realized that Objective-C's memory administration (all the `retains` and `releases`, etc.) can be fully automatized at *compile time*. This is, just by reading the code, even before it is run! :)

In order to do so there is only one condition: We MUST follow the [rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html), otherwise the compiler would not be able to automate the process at compile time. So, to ensure that we **never** break the rules, we are not allowed to explicitly write `release`, `retain`, etc. Those calls are Automatically injected into our code by the compiler. Hence internally we still have `autorelease`s, `retain`, `release`, etc. It is just we don't need to write them anymore.

The A of ARC is automatic at compile time, which is much better than at run time like garbage collection.

We still have `@autoreleasepool{...}` because having it does not break any of the rules, we are free create/drain our pool anytime we need it :).

Comment: ARC is reference counting GC, not mark-and-sweep GC like you get in JavaScript and Java, but it's definitely garbage collection.  This doesn't address the question--"you can" doesn't answer the question of "why should you".  You shouldn't.

Answer (score 6):

Autorelease pools are required for returning newly created objects from a method. E.g. consider this piece of code:

```
- (NSString *)messageOfTheDay {
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello %@!", self.username];
}
```

The string created in the method will have a retain count of one. Now who shall balance that retain count with a release?

The method itself? Not possible, it has to return the created object, so it must not release it prior to returning.

The caller of the method? The caller does not expect to retrieve an object that needs releasing, the method name does not imply that a new object is created, it only says that an object is returned and this returned object may be a new one requiring a release but it may as well be an existing one that doesn't. What the method does return may even depend on some internal state, so the the caller cannot know if it has to release that object and it shouldn't have to care.

If the caller had to always release all returned object by convention, then every object not newly created would always have to be retained prior to returning it from a method and it would have to be released by the caller once it goes out of scope, unless it is returned again. This would be highly inefficient in many cases as one can completely avoid altering retain counts in many cases if the caller will not always release the returned object.

That's why there are autorelease pools, so the first method will in fact become

```
- (NSString *)messageOfTheDay {
    NSString * res = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello %@!", self.username];
    return [res autorelease];
}
```

Calling `autorelease` on an object adds it to the autorelease pool, but what does that really mean, adding an object to the autorelease pool? Well, it means telling your system "*I want you to to release that object for me but at some later time, not now; it has a retain count that needs to be balanced by a release otherwise memory will leak but I cannot do that myself right now, as I need the object to stay alive beyond my current scope and my caller won't do it for me either, it has no knowledge that this needs to be done. So add it to your pool and once you clean up that pool, also clean up my object for me.*"

With ARC the compiler decides for you when to retain an object, when to release an object and when to add it to an autorelease pool but it still requires the presence of autorelease pools to be able to return newly created objects from methods without leaking memory. Apple has just made some nifty optimizations to the generated code which will sometimes eliminate autorelease pools during runtime. These optimizations require that both, the caller and the callee are using ARC (remember mixing ARC and non-ARC is legal and also officially supported) and if that is actually the case can only be known at runtime.

Consider this ARC Code:

```
// Callee
- (SomeObject *)getSomeObject {
    return [[SomeObject alloc] init];
}

// Caller
SomeObject * obj = [self getSomeObject];
[obj doStuff];
```

The code that the system generates, can either behave like the following code (that is the safe version that allows you to freely mix ARC and non-ARC code):

```
// Callee
- (SomeObject *)getSomeObject {
    return [[[SomeObject alloc] init] autorelease];
}

// Caller
SomeObject * obj = [[self getSomeObject] retain];
[obj doStuff];
[obj release];
```

(Note the retain/release in the caller is just a defensive safety retain, it's not strictly required, the code would be perfectly correct without it)

Or it can behave like this code, in case that both are detected to use ARC at runtime:

```
// Callee
- (SomeObject *)getSomeObject {
    return [[SomeObject alloc] init];
}

// Caller
SomeObject * obj = [self getSomeObject];
[obj doStuff];
[obj release];
```

As you can see, Apple eliminates the atuorelease, thus also the delayed object release when the pool is destroyed, as well as the safety retain. To learn more about how that is possible and what's really going on behind the scenes, [check out this blog post.](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-05-09-when-an-autorelease-isnt.html)

Now to the actual question: Why would one use `@autoreleasepool`?

For most developers, there's only one reason left today for using this construct in their code and that is to keep the memory footprint small where applicable. E.g. consider this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    // ... code ...
    TempObject * to = [TempObject tempObjectForData:...];
    // ... do something with to ...
}
```

Assume that every call to `tempObjectForData` may create a new `TempObject` that is returned autorelease. The for-loop will create one million of these temp objects which are all collected in the current autoreleasepool and only once that pool is destroyed, all the temp objects are destroyed as well. Until that happens, you have one million of these temp objects in memory.

If you write the code like this instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) @autoreleasepool {
    // ... code ...
    TempObject * to = [TempObject tempObjectForData:...];
    // ... do something with to ...
}
```

Then a new pool is created every time the for-loop runs and is destroyed at the end of each loop iteration. That way at most one temp object is hanging around in memory at any time despite the loop running one million times.

In the past you often had to also manage autoreleasepools yourself when managing threads (e.g. using `NSThread`) as only the main thread automatically has an autorelease pool for a Cocoa/UIKit app. Yet this is pretty much legacy today as today you probably wouldn't use threads to begin with. You'd use GCD `DispatchQueue`'s or `NSOperationQueue`'s and these two both do manage a top level autorelease pool for you, created before running a block/task and destroyed once done with it.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you still need to provide the compiler with hints about when it is safe for autoreleased objects to go out of scope.

Comment: Can you give me an example of when you would need to do this?

Comment: [Using Autorelease Pools](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000047-CJBFBEDI)

Comment: So before ARC, for example, I had a CVDisplayLink running on a secondary thread for my OpenGL app, but I didn't create an autorelease pool in its runloop because I knew I wasn't autorealeasing anything (or using libraries that do). Does that mean now I do need to add `@autoreleasepool` because I don't know if ARC might decide to autorelease something?

Comment: @Mk12 - No. You will always still have an auto release pool that gets drained each time round the main run loop. You should only need to add one when you want to ensure that objects that have been autoreleased get drained before they would otherwise - for example, the next time round the run loop.

Comment: @DougW - It's not a hint for when it's safe for autoreleased objects to go out of scope at all. It's also not the compiler that's concerned, it's all at runtime this.

Comment: Its on a secondary thread though, which doesn't have the main run loop's autorelease pool. I based my code on the apple sample code, which included the following in the beginning of the run loop method: `// We're on a secondary thread, so create an NSAutorelease pool
    // or else objects will be leaked.
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];`

Comment: @Mk12 - Oh sorry then, yes, you'd want an auto release pool. But if you use GCD then things will just magically work (as it creates an auto release pool for you). Sorry I missed the bit about secondary thread :-/.

Comment: @mattjgalloway - Okay yes, to be accurate it is more than a "hint".  But `@autoreleasepool` is not a runtime instruction.  It is a pre-compiler directive.  From Apple's docs: "This simple structure allows the compiler to reason about the reference count state.".

Comment: @DougW - It's true that the compiler will reason about the reference count state when using ARC - but there will still be auto releases going on at runtime and pools will be drained. It's now simpler (introduces a scope) for the compiler to understand if it actually needs to do an autorelease, i.e. it might be able to cancel out one autorelease with one retain. `@autoreleasepool` is not a runtime instruction, but there are still auto release pools that are drained at runtime.

Comment: @DougW - I took a look into what the compiler is actually doing and blogged about it here - http://iphone.galloway.me.uk/2012/02/a-look-under-arcs-hood-–-episode-3/ . Hopefully explains what's going on at both compile-time and run-time.

Comment: @mattjgalloway - Great write up.  I think we're all in agreement here, and I'm sure some folks are interested in reading a more detailed explanation than I gave, so thanks for providing it.

Answer (score 3):

Quoted from https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html:

> Autorelease Pool Blocks and Threads
>
> Each thread in a Cocoa application maintains its own stack of
>   autorelease pool blocks. If you are writing a Foundation-only program
>   or if you detach a thread, you need to create your own autorelease
>   pool block.
>
> If your application or thread is long-lived and potentially generates
>   a lot of autoreleased objects, you should use autorelease pool blocks
>   (like AppKit and UIKit do on the main thread); otherwise, autoreleased
>   objects accumulate and your memory footprint grows. If your detached
>   thread does not make Cocoa calls, you do not need to use an
>   autorelease pool block.
>
> Note: If you create secondary threads using the POSIX thread APIs
>   instead of NSThread, you cannot use Cocoa unless Cocoa is in
>   multithreading mode. Cocoa enters multithreading mode only after
>   detaching its first NSThread object. To use Cocoa on secondary POSIX
>   threads, your application must first detach at least one NSThread
>   object, which can immediately exit. You can test whether Cocoa is in
>   multithreading mode with the NSThread class method isMultiThreaded.

...

> In Automatic Reference Counting, or ARC, the system uses the same
>   reference counting system as MRR, but it insertsthe appropriate memory
>   management method callsfor you at compile-time. You are strongly
>   encouraged to use ARC for new projects. If you use ARC, there is
>   typically no need to understand the underlying implementation
>   described in this document, although it may in some situations be
>   helpful. For more about ARC, see Transitioning to ARC Release Notes.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

> Why is @autoreleasepool still needed with ARC?

`@autoreleasepool` is used by Objective-C and `autoreleasepool` by Swift to `release` objects which were put into auto release pool (by using `autorelease` inside) manually(not at the end of RunLoop iteration cycle)

When you work with pure Swift(without Objective-C objects) and allocate Swift objects - ARC handles it automatically

But if you decide call/use `Foundation/Legacy Objective-C code`(`NSData`, `Data`...) which uses `autorelese` inside then `@autoreleasepool` in a rescue

```
//Swift
//Data.init() uses Objective-C code with [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL] which uses `autorelese` inside
let imageData = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
```

[[MRC, ARC, GC]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77581901/4770877)

Answer (score -4):

There seems to be a lot of confusion on this topic (and at least 80 people who probably are now confused about this and think they need to sprinkle @autoreleasepool around their code).

If a project (including its dependencies) exclusively uses ARC, then @autoreleasepool never needs to be used and will do nothing useful.  ARC will handle releasing objects at the correct time.  For example:

```
@interface Testing: NSObject
+ (void) test;
@end

@implementation Testing
- (void) dealloc { NSLog(@"dealloc"); }

+ (void) test
{
    while(true) NSLog(@"p = %p", [Testing new]);
}
@end
```

displays:

```
p = 0x17696f80
dealloc
p = 0x17570a90
dealloc
```

Each Testing object is deallocated as soon as the value goes out of scope, without waiting for an autorelease pool to be exited.  (The same thing happens with the NSNumber example; this just lets us observe the dealloc.)  *ARC does not use autorelease.*

The reason @autoreleasepool is still allowed is for mixed ARC and non-ARC projects, which haven't yet completely transitioned to ARC.

If you call into non-ARC code, *it* may return an autoreleased object.  In that case, the  above loop would leak, since the current autorelease pool will never be exited.  That's where you'd want to put an @autoreleasepool around the code block.

But if you've completely made the ARC transition, then forget about autoreleasepool.

Comment: This answer is wrong and also goes against ARC documentation. your evidence is anecdotal because you happen to be using an allocation method that the compiler decides not to autorelease. You can very easily see this not working if you create a new static initializer for your custom class. Create this initializer and use it in your loop: `+ (Testing *) testing { return [Testing new] }`. Then you'll see that dealloc won't get called until later on. This is fixed if you wrap the  inside of the loop in an `@autoreleasepool` block.

Comment: @Dima Tried on iOS10, dealloc get called immediately after printing the object address. `+ (Testing *) testing { return [Testing new];} + (void) test { while(true) NSLog(@"p = %p", [self testing]);}`

Comment: @KudoCC - So did I, and I saw the same behavior that you did. But, when I threw `[UIImage imageWithData]` into the equation, then, all of a sudden, I started seeing the traditional `autorelease` behavior, requiring `@autoreleasepool` to keep peak memory to some reasonable level.

Comment: @Rob I can't help myself add the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840676/autorelease-pools-and-when-release-is-called-under-ios/19842107#19842107).