# Received memory warning and app crash while uploading more than 100 images on my server

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, didreceivememorywarning, memory-warning

I am uploading more than 100 images on server using following code and i Received memory warning after uploading few images. Please help me..
Here is my code for uploading image on sever :

```
-(void)uploadSingleFile
{
    if(!self.objWebServices.bSyncWasOn)
    {
        NSLog(@"STOP upload Single File RETURN");
        [self Call_SaveSyncedImageID];
        return;
    }
    SyncItem* item = [arrSelSyncItemIDS objectAtIndex:nSyncItemIndex];

    if(item.nType == SYNC_STATUS_NOT_SELECTED || item.nType == SYNC_STATUS_SYNC_DONE)
    {
        nSyncItemIndex = nSyncItemIndex + 1;
        if([arrSelSyncItemIDS count] > nSyncItemIndex)
        {
            NSLog(@"Called uploadSingleFile");
            [self uploadSingleFile];
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            //[self LoadImages:!bShowHideSyncImages];
            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
            [BtnStopSync setTitle:@"Start sync" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            self.objWebServices.bSyncWasOn = NO;
            self.objWebServices.isFileUpload = NO;

            if( [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"Notification_State"] ) // Setting Switch Bool
            {
                UIAlertView *Alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"test" message:@"*** Sync completed successfully." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [Alert show];
            }
        }
    }
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *srtprefSessionId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[prefs objectForKey:@"prefSessionId"]];

    BOOL isTrash = FALSE;   
    NSString *StrPath = @"/Pictures/";      //Change 
    ALAsset* temp = item.itemAsset;
    NSDate* assetDate = (NSDate*)[temp valueForProperty:@"ALAssetPropertyDate"];

    NSString* strID = @"";
    strID = [[temp valueForProperty:@"ALAssetPropertyURLs"] description];
    strID = [strID stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    NSString* strImageType = @"";
    if ([strID rangeOfString:@"jpg"].location != NSNotFound || [strID rangeOfString:@"JPG"].location != NSNotFound ){
        strImageType = @"jpg";
    }
    else if ([strID rangeOfString:@"png"].location != NSNotFound || [strID rangeOfString:@"PNG"].location != NSNotFound )
        strImageType = @"png";


    NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    NSString *result = [df stringFromDate:assetDate];

    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [assetDate timeIntervalSince1970];
    ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [temp defaultRepresentation];
    CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];
    StrPath = [StrPath stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d.%@",(int)timeInterval,strImageType];
    //UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[rep fullResolutionImage]];

    UIImage *image =[UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref scale:[rep scale] orientation:(UIImageOrientation)[rep orientation]];
    //------------------ metadata -------------------------------------------------------
    NSDictionary *imageMetadata = [rep metadata];
    NSString *strOrt=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[imageMetadata valueForKey:@"Orientation"]];

    NSData *dataObj = nil;
    dataObj = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
    NSString* StrFileData = [Base64 encode:dataObj];
    NSString* strFileHash = [dataObj md5Test];

    NSMutableDictionary *DictRequest = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [DictRequest setObject:srtprefSessionId forKey:@"SessionId"];
    [DictRequest setObject:StrPath forKey:@"Path"];
    [DictRequest setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:isTrash] forKey:@"UploadDirectlyToTrashbin"];
    [DictRequest setObject:StrFileData forKey:@"FileData"];
    [DictRequest setObject:strFileHash forKey:@"FileHash"];
    [DictRequest setObject:result forKey:@"DateCreated"];

    BOOL isNULL = [self stringIsEmpty:strOrt];
    if(!isNULL)
    {
        //[DictRequest setObject:strOrt forKey:@"Orientation"];
    }


    NSString *jsonString = [DictRequest JSONRepresentation];
    NSString *strUrl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",FileUpload_URL];
    NSURL *url1=[NSURL URLWithString:strUrl];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url1];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:60.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSData *postData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


    if(theConnection)
        [self Set2Defaults];

    theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

    if(theConnection)
        webData = [NSMutableData data];
    else
        NSLog(@"Connection Failed !!!");
}
```

Comment: That is a lot of code you want someone to debug for free. What have you done? What do you suspect is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-(void)uploadSingleFile
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
    ...
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: @Meena Yes you do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086913/objective-c-why-is-autorelease-autoreleasepool-still-needed-with-arc

Comment: but still i am getting same error  @9dan after 137 images uploaded

Comment: @Meena Standard approach for this kind of problem would be static analyzing (execute 'Analyze' command from the Xcode 'Product' menu). First of all, you must release `DictRequest` before return, theConnection when upload is done. Also need to ensure `webData` is not release prematurely by retaining it.

Comment: @Meena How about this? DictRequest = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init] autorelease]

Comment: @Meena then `DictRequest = [[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]` is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Why need of these many operations ????

```
NSData *dataObj = nil;
dataObj = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
NSString* StrFileData = [Base64 encode:dataObj];
NSString* strFileHash = [dataObj md5Test];
```

Also I suggest you to compress image before sending, since NSData will be huge. This can be managed from server side

Try compressing image before sending :

```
CGFloat compression = 0.9f;
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([item image], compression);
while ([imageData length] > 700000 && compression > 0.1) {
    // NSLog(@"Image size too big, compression more: current data size: %d bytes",[imageData length]);
    compression -= 0.1;
    imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([item image], compression);

}
```

Comment: yes i need to do this operations as i need it for my webservice

Comment: They might be taking more memory

Comment: i have tried using this code but still i am getting same memory warning

Comment: do you have any idea about this or is there any other way to upload image so that i can try other option

Answer (score 0):

Set up the `cachePolicy` to avoid cache

> request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData