# Autorelease pools and when release is called under iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsautoreleasepool

I wanted to get something clarified.

Lets say I have the following code:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
  for (int i = 0; i < 5000000; i++) {
    NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello, %@!", @"World"];
  }
}
```

This will create 5 million autoreleased strings within this function call. I was expecting this to keep those objects around until the termination of the application, as the only @autoreleasepool I see is the one wrapping the application instantiation in main.m. That's not the case, though. At the end of this function call, it seems they all get their release called and are removed from memory.

This document:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html

States that "The Application Kit creates an autorelease pool on the main thread at the beginning of every cycle of the event loop, and drains it at the end, thereby releasing any autoreleased objects generated while processing an event."

That makes sense to me, but this is under UIKit, and not Application Kit. My question is, does UIKit/Cocoa Touch do the same thing in this case, or is there another explanation for my objects getting released?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, UIKit does the same thing. The system-created, main thread autorelease pool is drained at the end of every run loop cycle. It's probably best not to rely on this exact lifetime in your own code. If you create a new thread manually (using e.g. NSThread), you're responsible for creating the autorelease pool on that thread.

EDIT: Rob's answer provides some good additional information regarding behavior under ARC. In general, it's fair to say that objects are less likely to end up in the autorelease pool due to some optimizations ARC is able to make.

Answer (score 20):

Andrew answered your main question that, yes, your autorelease pool will be drained on every cycle of the main run loop. So any autorelease objects created in `viewDidLoad` may promptly get drained when you yield back to the main run loop. They certainly won't be retained "until the termination of the application."

But we should be careful: You're clearly assuming that these objects are being added to an autorelease pool. A few caveats to this assumption:

1. In the past (and still required for ARC-MRC inter-operability), when returning objects from methods whose names did not start with `alloc`, `new`, `copy`, or `mutableCopy`, those objects would autorelease objects, deallocated only when the autorelease pool was drained (i.e. when you yielded back to the run loop).
2. But ARC has gotten smarter about minimizing the need for autorelease pools (see http://rentzsch.tumblr.com/post/75082194868/arcs-fast-autorelease, which discusses `callerAcceptsFastAutorelease`, now called `callerAcceptsOptimizedReturn` invoked by `prepareOptimizedReturn`), so you often will not see this `autorelease` behavior. So, if both the library and the caller are using ARC, objects may not be placed in the autorelease pool, but rather ARC will cleverly release them immediately if they're not needed.

   With contemporary ARC projects, autorelease pools are generally not needed. But certain special cases, one can still benefit from using autorelease pools. I'll outline one of those cases below.

Consider the following code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <sys/kdebug_signpost.h>

typedef enum : NSUInteger {
    InnerLoop = 1,
    MainLoop = 2
} MySignPostCodes;

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    NSURL *fileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"test" withExtension:@"png"];
    
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        kdebug_signpost_start(MainLoop, 0, 0, 0, 1);
        for (int j = 0; j < 500; i++) {
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];
            UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
            NSLog(@"%p", NSStringFromCGSize(image.size));  // so it's not optimized out
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.01];
        }
        kdebug_signpost_end(MainLoop, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    });
}

@end
```

The following code will add 500,000 objects to the autorelease pool, which will only be drained when I yield back to the run loop:

[image: no pool]

In this case, you might use an autorelease pool to minimize the high water mark:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    NSURL *fileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"test" withExtension:@"png"];
    
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        kdebug_signpost_start(MainLoop, 0, 0, 0, 1);
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            @autoreleasepool {
                kdebug_signpost_start(InnerLoop, 0, 0, 0, 2);
                for (long i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];
                    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
                    NSLog(@"%p", NSStringFromCGSize(image.size));  // so it's not optimized out
                    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.01];
                }
                kdebug_signpost_end(InnerLoop, 0, 0, 0, 2);
            }
        }
        kdebug_signpost_end(MainLoop, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    });
}

@end
```

[image: pool]

Bottom line, with ARC, it's not always obvious when it used an autorelease object and when it explicitly releases it when the variable falls out of scope. You can always confirm this by examining the behavior in Instruments.

As an aside, I'd be wary about drawing too many general memory management conclusions when using the `NSString` class, as it has been highly optimized and doesn't always conform to standard memory management practices.

Comment: "The following code will add 500,000 objects to the autorelease pool, which will only be drained when I yield back to the run loop" It's possible for ARC to release it immediately just like the second code, perhaps with optimization turned on.

Comment: I chose [NSString stringWithFormat:] because I know the returned object has autorelease called on it. All of this I knew previously, with the exception of the pool around each event, but thank you for the clarification. Hopefully it'll help someone else who stumbles upon this question :)

Comment: if `object = nil` deletes the original object from memory then possibly `object = [MyObject myObject]` deletes the original object from memory. Why would it be stored in autorelease pool under ARC?

Comment: @stefanB If you have an autorelease object (which the `[MyObject myObject]` code creates), `object = nil` (or simply letting the object fall out of scope) does not "delete" an object. It simply nils the pointer and leaves said object in the autorelease pool and the object will only be deallocated when the pool drains.

Comment: At first, I wonder if `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileURL]` is compiled with MRC though it seems a crazy thought, but even I use `[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];` instead or put `NSData` out of the for loop, I still get the same result. So that's right, in the method `[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data]`, something is autoreleased, very curious to know what it is and why apple does that. :(

Comment: It's not entirely surprising that images can be problematic because they're surprisingly complicated (the underlying asset, with a dizzying array of supported formats, is uncompressed only when necessary). But the "take home" message for me is not that images are problematic, but rather that as a general principle, while ARC will do its best to avoid using autorelease pools, we're not guaranteed that it will always succeed. I happened to stumble across one situation, but there may be others. Bottom line, ARC will perform this optimized return where it can, but there may always be edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that when you assign new object to a reference that used to hold an object then **the original object is released right away** (if nothing else points to it - ref count goes to zero) using ARC and asuming default `strong` reference as in your loop example.

```
MyObject *object = [[MyObject alloc] init]; // obj1, ref count 1 because strong
object = [[MyObject alloc] init]; // obj2, ref count of obj1 should be 0
                                  // so obj1 gets released
```

Apple notes in [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)

> Try to stop thinking about where the retain/release calls are put and think about your application algorithms instead. Think about “strong and weak” pointers in your objects, about object ownership, and about possible retain cycles.

It sounds that the `release` is called on object when it's assigned new value,
from clang [Clang 3.4 documentation
OBJECTIVE-C AUTOMATIC REFERENCE COUNTING (ARC)](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html)

> Assignment occurs when evaluating an assignment operator. The
>   semantics vary based on the qualification:
>
> For __strong objects, the new pointee is first retained; second, the
>   lvalue is loaded with primitive semantics; third, the new pointee is
>   stored into the lvalue with primitive semantics; and finally, the old
>   pointee is released. This is not performed atomically; external
>   synchronization must be used to make this safe in the face of
>   concurrent loads and stores.