# Does @autoreleasepool make sense in my scenario and in ARC?

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, autorelease, nsautoreleasepool

I parse the content of a file in order to create a set of `NSManagedObject` in a context and save them. This is the method where I do this:

```
- (BOOL)getEntitiesFromFileInContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
   BOOL result = YES;
   NSMutableArray *entities = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

   NSString *entitiesFileContent = [FilesManagerHelper readFile:fileName];

   if ([entitiesFileContent isEqualToString:@""]) {
       result = NO;
   }
   else {
       @autoreleasepool {
           entities = [self parseEntitiesFileContent:entitiesFileContent inContext:context];

           // If entities.count > 0, some operations here
       }

       // Save context and reset
       [self saveContext:context];
       [self clearContext:context];
   }

   return result;
}
```

In `parseEntitiesFileContent:inContext:` method I insert the `NSManagedObject` objects in the context I provide and I also add them to the `entities` array.

I'm performing this in an `@autoreleasepool` because I found an example doing that, but I'm not sure if it is really necessary... Could somebody explain me what the difference between using `@autoreleasepool` and not using it should be?

Thanks so much

**EDIT:** Should the `entities` array be defined inside the `@autoreleasepool` block?

Comment: I would expect a static analyser warning that says 'entities is never read'. Am I missing something - What is 'entities' purpose within the scope of this method?

Comment: @Bamsworld You're right, I missed some code there. Edited the code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because **entities** is declared within the scope of the method but not in the **autorelease pool block**, you have a strong pointer to **entities** outside the **autorelease pool block** and the **auto release pool** in this case will have no effect.

To verify this try logging **entities** just before the method returns.

For the **auto release pool block** to have some meaning, declare **entities** within the **auto release pool block**.

```
@autoreleasepool {
       NSMutableArray *entities = [self parseEntitiesFileContent:entitiesFileContent inContext:context];

       // If entities.count > 0, some operations here
   }
```

Now try and log **entities** straight after the auto release pool block.

This case is rather trivial if **entities** is small, however it is not a bad to include as it may help with scalability as this method may evolve over time and the auto release block starts to do more. If **entities** can be potentially large then you most definitely want the pool. My advice is to leave the auto release pool block and move the declaration of **entities** inside the pool block.

Answer (score 0):

The `@autorelase` statement implies creation of an autorelease pool that will contain all the objects that are marked as autorelease withing the scope of `@autorelease{}`. Thus, using `@autorelease` make sense if and only if there's a relatively considerable amount of autorelease-marked objects (it's needed not only of just-in-time memory deallocation but for avoiding "memory peaks" as well). Memory allocation and deallocation is a large topic to be explained in a single post, but the main rule is: use `@autorelease` for a scope if it's going to contain plenty of autorelease-marked objects.

Comment: Thanks, so... I'd use `@autorelease` only if I expect to get a very large file with objects to be parsed? The problem is that I don`t know beforehand how many objects I will have in such file. Would it be better to keep the ´@autorelease´ block just in case?

Comment: The answer to your questions is: "nor exactly". About the large amount of data: if you use 1 instance of NSData, it'll be either released (when you cease to use it) or retained by a strong reference if you assing the data to one. Keeping the @autorelease scope for no reason is an overkill. It all depends on how many "autorelease-marked" objects you use and on what you plan to do with those objects at the scope end. There's already a rich discussion on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086913/objective-c-why-is-autorelease-autoreleasepool-still-needed-with-arc. Hope it'll help.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation