# Loadin URL for Plist from Plist

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6, storyboard, plist

i try to load a plist file from other plist file using `initWithContentsOfURL:`

i explain, i have one table view using a plist file in my host, with this metod:

```
NSMutableArray *genres = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myurl.com/file.plist"]];
    self.loadGenres = genres;
```

when choose a cel loading other UITableView, but how can says to a second table view to get other plist from url using `<string>` inside the first plist?

Like a:

```
NSMutableArray *genres = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[self.loadGenres objectForKey:@"PLIST URL"]];
self.loadGenres = genres;
```

Thanks for support.

Comment: can you mention here what is the content of yout file.plist?

Comment: <key>gen</key><string>Carrot</string><key>source</key><string>spar.com</string><key>image</key><string>genresC.png</string><key>file</key><string>http://www.myurl.com/file.plist</string>

Comment: i Will get the file string in a second TableView

Comment: so you want to access the string "spar.com" from this file in code?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Key-Value coding in Array's.

Instead try like this,

```
NSMutableDictionary * genres = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myurl.com/file.plist"]];
self.loadGenres = genres; // your self.loadGenres must be Dictionary type

NSMutableDictionary * genres = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[self.loadGenres objectForKey:@"PLIST URL"]stringValue]]];
self.loadGenres = genres;
```

Comment: Hmmm i try it before, but the error message is: No visible @interface for 'NSMutableArray' declares the selector 'objectForKey:'

Answer (score 1):

try the following
in YourClass.h

```
NSURLConnection* linksConnection;
NSMutableData* linksData;
```

in YourClass.m

```
-(void) loadURL
{

NSMutableURLRequest* the_request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL        URLWithString:YOUR_URL]];
linksConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:the_request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

if(linksConnection != nil)
{
    linksData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];

}
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
 [linksData setLength:0];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
[linksData appendData:data];
}

-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

NSString *errorStr = nil;
NSPropertyListFormat format;
NSDictionary *propertyList = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:linksData
                                                              mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable
                                                                        format:&format
                                                              errorDescription:&errorStr];
NSMutableArray*  myArray = [[propertyList objectForKey:@"sample"] retain];
}
```

I am sure this will help you a lot

Comment: You can disable ARC in your project settings besides it is not a good practise to use Automatic Referencing Counting

Comment: see this for disabling the ARC http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837024/how-to-disable-xcode4-2-automatic-reference-counting

Comment: well If that worked for you you can mark my answer as correct;)