# How can I fix this error: "ARC forbids explicit message send of 'release' in Xcode"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to make a simple animation image in iPhone from an image array:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSArray *imageArray;
    imageArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"sun1"],
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"sun2"],
                  nil];
    fadeImage.animationImages = imageArray;
    fadeImage.animationDuration = 1;
    [imageArray release];  //==== HERE IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR ======
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You can disable ARC as your choice

Go [this link][1], and try that.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Xcode has the tool "Edit:Refactor:Convert to Objective-C ARC".

Answer (score 80):

**Solution #1:**

Just remove the release statement. ARC will manage it for you.

```
[imageArray release]; // remove this line
```

ARC is Auto Reference Counting. As opposite to manual reference counting.

There are a few great videos of talks from WWDC. I can provide  the link if you wish to watch them.

**In [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html), see *ARC Enforces New Rules*:**

> You cannot explicitly invoke dealloc, or implement or invoke retain,
>   **release**, retainCount, or autorelease.
>
> The prohibition extends to using @selector(retain),
>   @selector(release), and so on.

**Solution #2:**

If you do not wish to convert the code to ARC (e.g. you are not writing a new application, but are maintaining an old one / or you imported so much code that moving to ARC is not worth it) you can disable ARC.

- **Disabling ARC for selected files** To disable ARC, you can use the `-fno-objc-arc` compiler flag for specific files. Select the target
  and go to `Build Phases` -> `Compile Sources`. Edit the `Compiler
  Flags` and add `-fno-objc-arc`
- **Disabling ARC for the project** 
  *Source:[How to disable Xcode4.2 Automatic Reference Counting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837024/how-to-disable-xcode4-2-automatic-reference-counting)*

  - Click on you project, in the left hand organizer.
  - Select your target, in the next column over.
  - Select the Build Settings tab at the top.
  - Scroll down to "Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting" (it may be    listed as
  - "CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC" under the User-Defined settings group), and    set it to NO.

Comment: You should probably elaborate on solution #2, though. Specifically, the `-fno-objc-arc` flag is your friend.

Comment: I removed the line...

Comment: Sorry I press return... I removed the line and I got this return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class])); and the error Thread 1: signal SIGABRT  I'm just trying to make a simple animation, thank you for taking the time to answer this question wherever you are

Comment: Still no luck with the animation problem, any body knows how to make a simple animation on Xcode?

Comment: @VictorBarba `SIGABRT` means a serious, unrecoverable, error occurred and `abort()` was called. Where did you get the code? Is it compatible with your app's memory management? Are you linking to a 3rd party developer framework? Have you tried disabling ARC entirely? Since we are drifting out of the topic of this question (*why `[anObject release];` produces an error under ARC*), maybe you could open a new question about getting the `SIGABRT` signal, in which you would provide more details, including a short, self contained, compilable, example. This way we could help better.

Comment: Solution two worked for me to get NSLogger working. Thanks!