# Disable ARC for entire nested project in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I am using a xcode sub project inside my main project. My main project is ARC enabled but the sub project is MRC project So how can I tell the compiler that my entire sub project is not ARC supported instead setting **-fno-objc** for all .m files in build phase.

Comment: -fno-objc-arc in yout .m file

Comment: I also had the same problem once.Check <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837024/how-to-disable-xcode4-2-automatic-reference-counting">this</a> out. This might help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to disabled for the whole project, go to your target's build settings and set Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting to **No**.

Like this:

[image]

Comment: unfortunatelly, I've got an old project which is used as a subproject, which has ARC set to No, but it's still giving errors about dealloc/retain etc. it's trying to compile with ARC on.

Comment: one of the source files from the old project was accidentally added to compile sources phase of the new project, that was why, solved. nevermind.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to Disable ARC for entire group of files of youe nested project

Goto Build Phases -> Compile sources select multiple files holding command ⌘ and press enter then add the value **-fno-objc-arc** It will reflect for all the selected files.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : Goto the Target -> Build Settings -> Under Apple LLVM 6.0 - Language - Objective C -> Set Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting to NO.